# How to see a list of MySQL users through terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal

I have a client server where I have SSH access but the client does not have a record of the various MySQL user accounts and passwords. I'm happy to reset/change passwords if required but how do I go about doing this and getting at a list of MySQL users and the databases they have access to via terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(USER),'@',QUOTE(HOST)) UserAccount FROM mysql.user;
```

This query will give you all MySQL user account details added in MySQL server.
Later you can change password for each user using `mysqladmin` tool

```
 mysqladmin -u USER -p password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: Sorry to be a noob but I'm guessing I can't just type that into terminal, do I need to 'log-in to MySQL' through terminal first???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT User,Host FROM mysql.user;
```

This query displays users and the host level.